# Remove Text from textbox in VBA when the form reruns

Tags: vba, forms

I have a form in witch i have some textboxs. After i complet the textboxt i check a few checkbox and hit the start button it writes something in a file and it restarts but it keeps my old text and checks. I want a simple comand to remove the text and checks; i want it to restart my form like it never ran

Answer (score 0):

You should always call `Unload` when you are finished with a form.  This will remove the form from memory so that next time it is used it is initialised to its original state.

eg:

```
Unload Form1
```